# Dynamically edit columns in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Context**

I am creating a database of stock price data. I am currently using the below `onEdit` function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the spreadsheet that this will apply to, the tabs and columns
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var excludeTabs = ["Summary", "FTSE 250"];
  var excludeColumns = [1,2,12,13,14,15,16]; // the columns to isolate for special reasons
  var excludeCells = ["M1","I1","I2"];
  // What is the criteria for action to be taken? If the terms defined in excludeTabs are met, then move onto the next criteria (indexOf used because we stored it as an array
  if(excludeTabs.indexOf(ss.getName())===-1){
    // The range from the spreadsheet. 
    // Scripts expects an event in a cell
    var cell = e.range;
    // For the entire column of this cell
    var col = cell.getColumn();
    // Within the universe of tabs that this script applies to, we want to exclude the columns in the array
    if(excludeColumns.indexOf(col)===-1)
      // Within the universe of tabs and columns, we want to exclude certain cells
      if(excludeCells.indexOf(cell)===-1)
      // Need to make sure it only applies to formulas
        if(cell.getFormula() !== ""){ 
          var destination = ss.getRange(4, col, ss.getLastRow()-1, 1); 
          cell.copyTo(destination);  
      }//End of the remaining universe of data taking out the exceptions
     }//End Tab criteria
}//End function
```

This allows for an edit in some of the columns to be performed when I edit the cell. So far it works but with a few kinks.

**Problem 1**

Sometimes, when I edit a cell above the fourth row of a column, it edits the entire column despite me telling it to start from the fourth row. This happened just a few minutes ago in a cell I told it to exclude above "I2". Is there anything wrong with the code I have written to this effect?

**Problem 2**
I tried creating other exceptions for the code, where for some specified ranges, it will only edit from a different cell range. Not the fourth cell of every column but of say the 10th cell. I tried adding it below `var destination = ss.getRange(4, col, ss.getLastRow()-1, 1)` but it did not work. I also tried creating a separate onEdit function for a different cell location but it also did not work.

So far I have been using the sheet formulas like the below:
`IFERROR(IFS(C4="Returns","",AND(C4="",C5="",C6="",C7="",C8=""),"",AND(ISNUMBER(C4),ISNUMBER(C5),ISNUMBER(C6),ISNUMBER(C7),ISNUMBER(C8)),COVAR($C4:$C8,'FTSE 250'!J5:J9)),""))`

But this just gets messy. Sometimes there is data in the cell and so it would render formulas like the above useless. An example is the below picture.

**Update** I want the onEdit to start and drag down from the 10th row of the column but only for that column (this is the row in that column that I will be editing). I also want to be able to do this for other columns (start the automatic copy down process from different rows).

- This is the range I am trying to edit

[[image: Range I am trying to edit (starting from the 5th day of the week)1]

**Update 2**

`...`

```
 if(!excludeTabs.includes(ss.getName()) &&  
     !excludeColumns.includes(col) &&
     !excludeCells.includes(cell.getA1Notation()) &&
     cell.getFormula() !== ""
    ){
      
    if(col==33){
      var destination = ss.getRange(8, col, ss.getMaxRows()-7, 1);
      cell.copyTo(destination);    
    }

   else if(col===30){
          var destination = ss.getRange(8, col, ss.getMaxRows()-7, 1);
          cell.copyTo(destination); 
        }

    else{
    var destination = ss.getRange(4, col, ss.getMaxRows()-3, 1);
    cell.copyTo(destination);    
      }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

**Issues:**

- Your `if` statements don't have closed brackets with code in it.
- Here `if(excludeCells.indexOf(cell)===-1)` there is a problem:

  `var excludeCells = ["M1","I1","I2"];` is an array of strings and `var cell = e.range;` is a range object. You are actually comparing two different things (a `string` vs a `range` object.)

  Instead you want to **replace**: `if(excludeCells.indexOf(cell)===-1)` **with** `if(excludeCells.indexOf(cell.getA1Notation())===-1)`.

**Improvements:**

- Instead of using multiple `if` statements which at the end lead to one single code block, use one `if` statement with multiple conditions.
- Also this range `getRange(4, col, ss.getLastRow()-1, 1);` does not make a lot of sense either. It makes more sense to use `ss.getLastRow()-3` because you are starting from `3`.
- Instead of using `excludeCells.indexOf(cell.getA1Notation())===-1` which is a long expression, you can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like that `!excludeCells.includes(cell.getA1Notation())`.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var excludeTabs = ["Summary", "FTSE 250"];
  var excludeColumns = [1,2,12,13,14,15,16]; // the columns to isolate for special reasons
  var excludeCells = ["M1","I1","I2"];
  var cell = e.range;
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  
  if(!excludeTabs.includes(ss.getName()) &&  
     !excludeColumns.includes(col) &&
     !excludeCells.includes(cell.getA1Notation()) &&
     cell.getFormula() !== ""
    ){         
      if(col==33){
       var destination = ss.getRange(10, col, ss.getMaxRows()-9, 1);
       cell.copyTo(destination);    
      }
      else{
       var destination = ss.getRange(4, col, ss.getMaxRows()-3, 1);
       cell.copyTo(destination);    
      }
     }
}
```

**Please Note:**

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) returns the last row with content. For example if you have 10 columns and the first `10` have last row with content to be `55` but there is a random value in column `20` at the end of the sheet let's say row `900` then `900` will be the last row in your sheet. Be careful with that, otherwise you will need other approach to get the last row with content. Formulas are content too. So a formula all the way to the bottom of the sheet might determine what `getLastRow` returns.

Comment: Thanks for this, this solved the first problem. I have tested and it is working. I have updated the second issue in the original post. Apologies, I was not clear on this. Let me know if it needs further clarity.

Comment: @Desmond check my updated answer. But again not 100% sure what you meant. You want to copy the value/formula of the cell you just edited to a range of cells starting from row 10 all the way to the bottom of the sheet for the particular column you edited?

Comment: Yeah sorry. Okay, so the first answer was okay. I want the first one to exist as a function. But I also want the possibility to exclude range AG as indicated in the picture above and make this onEdit to start from row 10 because the calculation is being done on the last day of that week which is located in the 10th row. So on the 10th row and beyond on Edit should work in conjunction with having the previous formula which applies to the entirety of the sheet.

Comment: So onEdit should be able to do two things. The first is to drag down from the fourth row for the entire sheet with listed exceptions. The second should apply for a different column range, AG, to start from the 10th row down but only for this row. I want to know the framework so that I can do it for other 'special columns' that have different time ranges when I calculate the math equations.

Comment: Wil this mean I have to 1. create an exclusion like above for the listed columns, 2. create a separate onEdit function?

Comment: @Desmond No. See my answer. You can have another `if` condition at the end to check if the edited column is `AG` which is column `33`. Let me know if this is what you want. Also you want to allow for edits on every cell or on particular rows? For example, run the code only when you edit rows `1` to `4` or something.

Comment: Thanks for this! I get the logic thanks. Its not working. Other cells are also not copying across the remainder of the columns. To your question, I want it to run for every row in that column `AG, (33)`

Comment: do you get any errors? go to execution page and tell me if you get any errors. Literally, I used exactly the same code as before but I just created a super simple `if `that checks if the column is `AG`. Please post errors or test it again. To remind you also, you have excluded a couple of columns, so you might be testing it for the wrong columns. Also make sure your edit is a `formula` since this is part of the conditions. If none of them work, then please share a mock sheet (remove sensitive info) so we can find the solution. This will save us both a lot of time. @Desmond

Comment: Dw, it works. My apologies, I forgot to delete part of the old code so it was not running properly. Thanks again!! :D

Comment: One last issue - I tried adding another If statement, though it works for the other column, it stopped working for col 33. I have attached the code in the original post.

Comment: @Desmond I fixed your code in your question but please if you have follow up questions I would suggest you to create another post. Your current question, my answer and the comment section became super huge and no future reader will benefit from this post. Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var excludeTabs = ["Summary", "FTSE 250"];
  var excludeColumns = [1,2,12,13,14,15,16]; 
  var excludeCells = ["M1","I1","I2"];
  if(excludeTabs.indexOf(sh.getName())==-1 && excludeColumns.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)==-1 && excludeCells.indexOf(e.range.getA1Notation())==-1 && e.range.getFormula()!=""){    
      e.range.copyTo(sh.getRange(4, e.range.columnStart, sh.getLastRow()-3, 1));//The numbers of rows to the bottom is sh.getLastRow()-3 -1 will have to roll off of the bottom of the spreadsheet which will give you out of range errors  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice you were there. I should have refreshed the page before posting.  I just took the op's code and took all of the junk out of it.

Comment: Its fine, both work, the more the merrier. I have updated the second problem. Thanks to both of you!